# Setting currentTime in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I Am trying to set a currentTime while streaming a audio src from a server. On every other browser this works fine, however on IE9 when i set currentTime and call play, it jumps back to the beginning.

```
this.playAtTime = function(aTime) {
    Debug("play at time audio: " + aTime);
    Debug("this.mAudioPlayer.currentTime: " + this.mAudioPlayer.currentTime);

     this.startTime = aTime;

    if (this.mAudioPlayer.src != this.mAudioSrc) {
        this.mAudioPlayer = new Audio();
        this.mAudioPlayer.src = this.mAudioSrc;
        this.mAudioPlayer.load();
        this.mAudioPlayer.play();
        this.mAudioPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){ this.currentTime = aTime / 1000.0; }, false );
    }
    else if ((isChrome() || isMobileSafari()) && aTime == 0) {
        this.mAudioPlayer.load();
        this.mAudioPlayer.currentTime = aTime / 1000.0;
        this.mAudioPlayer.play();
        Debug("Reloading audio");
    }else{

        this.mAudioPlayer.currentTime = aTime / 1000.0;
        this.mAudioPlayer.play();
    }       
};
```

This isnt a issue of buffering because no matter how long it waits it wont succeed at setting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try exchanging the position of the below two line:

```
this.mAudioPlayer.play();
this.mAudioPlayer.currentTime = aTime / 1000.0;
```

Comment: That worked! thank you. I would be curious to know why it works on other browsers and not IE specifically. I am guessing that .play() always sets currentTime to 0, and you can only set currentTime while its playing?

Comment: even while playing currentTime can be used to set the time for playing the audio, so above method works, but i don't know why IE starts playing from 0th position when play() is called(maybe it only works with pause)